# How to match the answer in vb.net and asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I random the 3 question to display on asp.net page. I want to match the security question with correct answer in database. But after I enter the correct answer in textbox and click the "Next" button, the answer cannot match the current question displayed on screen. But if I click the "Next" button, the next question displayed is matched with answer I enter on textbox  in previous question. I think this is because the answer is match the question and answer after refresh the page. Please help. Here is my code. thanks

vb.net code

```
Dim SecurityQuestion As New DBDataContext
Dim randomNumber As Integer

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim SecurityQuestion As New DBDataContext
    Dim rowCount As Integer = (From t In SecurityQuestion.tblSecurityQuestions Select t).Count + 1
End Sub

Protected Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    ValidateAnswer()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadSecurityQuestion()
    Dim SecurityQuestion As New DBDataContext
    Dim mySecurityQuestion = (From c In SecurityQuestion.tblSecurityQuestions Where c.PkID = randomNumber Select c)
    Dim rowCount As Integer = (From t In SecurityQuestion.tblSecurityQuestions Select t).Count + 1
    randomNumber = New Random().Next(1, rowCount)
    With gvQuestion
        .DataSource = mySecurityQuestion
        .DataBind()
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateAnswer()
    Dim SecurityQuestion As New DBDataContext
    Dim validate = (From r In SecurityQuestion.tblRegistrations From s In SecurityQuestion.tblSecurityQuestions _
        Where s.PkID = r.Q01 And r.A01 = txtSecurityAns.Text And r.UserID = ad And s.PkID = randomNumber _
        Select r)

    If validate.Count > 0 Then
        Msg3.Text = "Correct Answer"
    Else
        Msg3.Text = "Invalid Answer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where u r calling this LoadSecurityQuestion() method? plz post the full source code.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I posted this answer, it *looked* like a small bit of your code *might* have been missing.  As an example, I couldn't see where you were actually calling the method LoadSecurityQuestion, but it *sounds* like you may be acidentally re-calling the method LoadSecurityQuestion even after validation succeeds.

I *think* you can fix this problem by wrapping your call to LoadSecurityQuestion with an "if" qualifier.  As an example, lets *suppose* that you were calling LoadSecurityQuestion in your Load Event handler.  If you did that, your new Load event handler might read something like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ...
    If IsPostBack Then
        ' If you wrap all of your Me.LoadSecurityQuestion calls 
        ' with "If" statements like this one, then it should keep
        ' the security question from changing when the user 
        ' enters the correct answer
        If Msg3.Text <> "Correct Answer" Then                
            Me.LoadSecurityQuestion()
        End If
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```